Magento 2 Cutomisable Option Price Issue when switch currency
It seems you've encountered an issue with Magento 2.4.5 and lower versions when dealing with currency conversion for customizable options. Here’s a clearer description of the
steps and the problem:
Steps to Reproduce the Issue:

Create a Catalog Price Rule:


Assign it to a customer group, such as "General."


Assign a Customizable Option with a Price to a Product:


For example, add a customizable option priced at $20.


Set Up Currency Switcher:


Configure two currencies, such as USD and INR.


Set Up Currency Rate:


For instance, set the rate so that 1 USD = 80 INR.


Frontend Actions:


Log in as a customer who is assigned to the catalog price rule.
Go to the product page.
Change the currency from USD to INR.

Issue Observed:

When changing the currency, the customizable option price is converted twice.

Actual Result: If the customizable option price is $20, it is converted as follows:
20 * 80 = 1600 and then 1600 * 80 = 128000.
Expected Result: The price should only be converted once: 20 * 80 = 1600.
I did not encounter this issue in Magento 2.4.6. I have also tried to find a patch, but I couldn't locate one. Can you help me?

This is Bug in magento version 2.4.5, for that you need to install this path ACSD-47107 into your system.
To install the patch, you can use this command :
composer require magento/quality-patches

You will get more information from here :
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-operations/tools/quality-patches-tool/usage

Thanks, it work for me and resolve my issue.
